# QGIS not reading elevations from GeoTIFF created by ACADCIVIL?

Tags: qgis-3

I've generated a raster DEM in ACADCIVIL in TIFF format: name.tif & name.tif.aux.xml.
ArcGIS reads the data correctly but QGIS sets the whole data to the same value = minimum height
Looks that QGIS 3.4 doesn't support this format.
Same happens on 2.18

```
gdalinfo output:

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Surface1.tif
       Surface1.tif.aux.xml
Size is 405, 528
Coordinate System is:
LOCAL_CS["POSGAR_07_F5",
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (5512262.832999999634922,6109047.309000000357628)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Autodesk Civil3D 2008
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 5512262.833, 6109047.309) 
Lower Left  ( 5512262.833, 6108519.309) 
Upper Right ( 5512667.833, 6109047.309) 
Lower Right ( 5512667.833, 6108519.309) 
Center      ( 5512465.333, 6108783.309) 
Band 1 Block=405x100 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=38.088 Max=39.473 
  Minimum=38.088, Maximum=39.473, Mean=38.565, StdDev=0.301
  NoData Value=3.4028234663852886e+38
  Offset: 38.082,   Scale:0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=9.08270199017587E-02
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=39.473079681396
    STATISTICS_MEAN=38.564526756118
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=38.088008880615
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.30137388124225
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=52.86
```

I've changed scale to 1 --> same result
File Properties --> Info
Band

Number Band    No-Data    Min   Max
1    Band 1  3.40282e+38  n/a   n/a

Comment: Run gdalinfo for your DEM file and add the report into your question.

Comment: QGIS reads all [GDAL raster formats](https://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html), GeoTIFF file format included. It seems to me rather a problem of installation of GDAL. A screenshot of the QGIS _About_ window, and the _Information_ tab of the layer _Properties_ could also be useful.

Comment: Offset and Scale parameters can be the problem?

Comment: Offset is a fixed value added to all the cell values, it should be 0. Scale is a multiplying factor for all cell values, it should be 1. `gdal_translate -a_offset 0 -a_scale 1 Surface1.tif somefilename.tif` don't solve the issue?

Comment: Even if I a edit the surface1.tif.aux.xml the data isn't considered, so this file isn't read at all, it's just readable user info. After executing your command everything works as expected. So we have to blame Autodesk on this. I'll keep your command to fix future DEMs generated by ACAD. Thanks a lot buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine in the GeoTIFF file info, except the Offset and Scale values.

Offset is a fixed value added to all the cell values, it should be 0.
Scale is a multiplying factor for all cell values, it should be 1.

Therefore, you need to make a translate:

`gdal_translate -a_offset 0 -a_scale 1 Surface1.tif somefilename.tif`

QGIS can now correctly represent the generated file.