# How to show elevation data from TIFF file in QGIS

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I work many times with QGIS and CIVIL3D, and when I create a surface from Civil 3D and export it as a TIFF file in order to open it in QGIS 3.4, the elevation data from this TIFF file appears "flat" (i.e. the same elevation throughout the area). However, strangely enough, when I extract contours, these are correct. I do not know how to fix this problem. I attached a snapshot.

[image]

Comment: The *Earth* is flat, relative to horizontal distances. Have you tried applying vertical exaggeration to your surface?

Comment: Hi @Adrián, welcome to GIS.SE! This issue was already answered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309294/qgis-not-reading-elevations-from-geotiff-created-by-acadcivil/309299#309299). If that's not your case, please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/309616/edit) detailing that you have read that question-answer and why it does not correspond to your case..